# Apache log4j upgrade on JBoss 7.1.1 on Windows server

Tags: windows, security, jboss, log4j

I have to upgrade Apache log4j to a version that is currently supported on a Windows server with JBoss 7.1.1.Final which has log4j-1.2.16.jar version.
Since I haven't done it before and I am also not very familiar with log4j vulnerability solutions and their integrations especially in JBoss, I would kindly ask for help here.

I found that log4j files are inside this location on the machine :
E:\jboss-7.1.1\modules\org\apache\log4j\main\log4j-1.2.16.jar

There is also module.xml file in this location, with the aforementioned log4j JAR file specified inside.

I am not sure if just downloading the newest supported logj4 version file and replacing it in the location, and also modifying the module.xml file will be enough for this activity, so I will be glad if someone can advise me on this in more details.

Thank you

Comment: All versions of log4j should be supported on Windows. Are you referring to JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final here or JBoss EAP 7.1?

Comment: Hello, yes I am referring to JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final exactly

Comment: In JBoss AS 7 a forked version of log4j is used. Newer versions are compiled to Java 8. The project itself, https://github.com/jboss-logging/log4j-jboss-logmanager, will likely not see any more updates as log4j itself has been EOL'ed for a long time now. You could try upgrading the library and updating the `module.xml` to point to new library.